# Which code does a servlet context use to match the requestedURI and servlet urlPatterns?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I created a java annotation and use it on servlet methods, so methods will be invoked from servlet service() method.

Like this:

```
@Run(Address="/abc/*",Priority=1)
public void doSomething(){}
```

So, i need exactly the code snippet which servlet contexts use to match the requestedURI and servlet urlPatterns.

I don't want to use regular expressions, want to follow the approach java servlet uses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If only it were that simple. The process of mapping a URI to the correct servlet is non-trivial. Tomcat has a separate [Mapper class](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/mapper/Mapper.java?view=annotate) to do this.